# Java - NoClassDefFoundError in mixed maven and non maven projects

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, maven, jar

1. I have a maven rest server
2. It uses a maven based jar file
3. This maven based jar file is linked to a **non maven** other jar file.

Everything compiles perfectly.

But, when sending a request on the rest server, I get a NoClassDefFoundError exception on some class from the non maven jar.

Any ideas about this problem?

Comment: Is the class-path set up correctly? I don't think maven will set this up for non-maven files. You might want to only use maven-jar files, it's not hard to just install a non-maven jar file as artifact to your maven repository.

Answer (score 0):

I call "maven based jar file" jarA  and "non maven jar" jarB.

1. add jarB to your local maven repository, [following this guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).
2. add jarB to the dependencies of jarA (via `pom.xml` of jarA). Use the same maven coordinates for jarB from the first step.
3. on the REST service, call `mvn clean package`, then deploy it